# AC pressure switch tripped / failed?

Tags: electrical, hvac

Long story short AC stopped working went to investigate found issue to be pressure switch

[image: https://imgur.com/4WskzMc]

[image: https://imgur.com/pdklJGE]

(presumably, not sure if switch is high or low side) push to reset switch seems fine (image shows continuity)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTtNu.jpg]

and I am getting proper "activation" voltage (shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTtNu.jpg) (not sure what the correct term is), contactor activates fine if I hook it up directly.

Is it a pressure issue? has the switch failed?
What should I do, can I bypass that switch temporarily (so half my house isn't 90°)? Is it even possible to replace such a switch without removing all of the refrigerant? 
Edit: I seem to get voltage through the switch but when I connect the other end to the contactor it drops off. In other words the switch seems to be high resistance and not completely cut off, this leads me to believe the switch is faulty

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you now that the condenser should be cleaned but I guess that's off topic.  If you are confident about the switch then most likely you will have to reclaim the refrigerant, replace the switch, pull vacuum and replace refrigerant.  Minimum items needed, Reclaiming pump, Reclaim cylinder, vacuum pump, gauge set, etc.  You'll need a service tech for this one.  If you do bypass it, clean the condenser because because that can cause an elevated head pressure.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. Posted this to Reddit and got nothing but people yelling at me about the coil (which I do clean on a yearly basis). I heard from someone that these are connected with a Schrader valve, are they?

Comment: Some are and some are not.  Schrader valves tend to be a common leak point so they are avoided whenever possible is my observation.

Comment: Okay I guess I'll clean the coil and bypass the pressure switch temporarily until I can get a technician with the recovery machine to do the job. Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay since I've been in the AC I decided to check the capacitor. The writing on the side says it's a 35 micro farad capacitor when this compressor calls for a 50 microfarad capacitor could this have caused the problem?

Comment: I should also mention that I was not the one to replace this capacitor, perhaps the lower value capacitor cause the compressor to overheat?

Comment: Usually not but I would replace the capacitor anyway.  The compressor will overheat when you exceed the RLA.  Again you will need a special device to measure that (fluke meter) and that could indicate one of many items.  Too many to list here but one of them is a dirty condenser, lol.  So clean that and do your bypass and run it but consider getting a reputable tech there.  I happen to be an HVAC technician.

Comment: High pressure safety switches usually have a reset, many do have Schrader valves in front of them so they can be replaced. The part number would be helpful to know if it is NO or NC, they rarely go bad. There are 2 different sizes of lines going to the compressor. The smaller one is the high pressure side the larger one is the low pressure or suction line.